# "Key Not Found" error in LevelDB

Tags: c++, leveldb

I'm using levelDb in my program.

Now sometimes (I can't say whe exactly and in what frequency) When I'm using `Db->Get()` 
I'm getting a "key not found" error despite the key exists.

When I'm using the iterator, 
I'm able to retrieve the key.

I'm using Linux OS Centos 6.6 , C++ Interface

Any explanation or a lead to why I may be getting this error would be appreciated.

Comment: my guess. check case, 0 vs O, I vs 1, unprintable chars, trailing or leading whitespace etc on the missing key. Code would be nice too

Comment: Is your key field case sensitive?  For example, do you want 'k' == 'K'?

Comment: Maybe you can add the access behavior of the key that you miss. Deletion command toward that key exists?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've checked my keys raw binary and I can access them via iterator, but not with `Db->Get()`. This only affects some keys, but not others. Have you found a solution?